# When is it permissible to follow a minority opinion?

Tags: fiqh, ijma

Salaam. I have a question about difference of opinions amongst scholars. Let's say the majority of scholar view a certain action as haram but a minority of scholars view that action as halal,and I find that the arguments of minority are stronger.

Would it then be permissible for me to follow the minority opinion? In addition, if it turns out that the minority view is incorrect, would the sin be held against me? Jazakhallah.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are referring to?.

Comment: Tell us what fatwa that you are referring to? So that we can factcheck that.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem I am referring to the matter of commercial insurance. Majority of scholars view it as impermissible, but there are quite a few scholars in the minority who say it is permissble and I find their arguments stronger.

Comment: The [tag:islamic-scholar] doesn't look related here as you are not asking about a specific person.